# Application crash when close com port in a background worker - C# application?

Tags: c#, serial-port, thread-safety

I had done a quick-search and still cant find the answer for my question .

Serial port variable

```
int close;
SerialPort _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1", 1200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
```

Serial port delegate code

```
private void si_DataReceived(string data)
{
    if (close == 1)
    {
        string d1 = data.Trim().Replace("TT", "");
        d1 = d1.Replace("Tl3", "");
        txtCan.Text = d1;
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }

}
private delegate void SetTextDeleg(string text);
void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string data = _serialPort.ReadLine();
    this.BeginInvoke(new SetTextDeleg(si_DataReceived), new object[] { data });
}
```

Connect button code

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (button4.Text == "Close Connection")
    {
        progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
        progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0;
        close=0;
        try
        {
            string d1 = txtCan.Text;
            double r1 = Convert.ToDouble(d1) * 10;
            txtCan.Text = Math.Round(r1, 3).ToString();
            button4.Text = "Open Connection";
            button1.Enabled = true;
            readOnly(true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            button4.Text = "Open Connection";
            button1.Enabled = true;
            progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
            progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0;
            MessageBox.Show("Cant connect.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
        progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 30;
        close = 1;
        txtCan.Text = "";
        txtCan.Focus();
        readOnly(false);
        button1.Enabled = false;
        button4.Text = "Close Connection";
        try
        {
            if(!_serialPort.IsOpen)
            { 
                _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
                _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);
                _serialPort.Open();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            button4.Text = "Open Connection";
            button1.Enabled = true;
            readOnly(true);
            progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
            progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 0;
            MessageBox.Show("Cant connect.");
        }
    }
}
```

My solution to close a com port, but it will fail if I re-open a form in countable times (like twice or triple times then it will crash)

```
private void myForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (_serialPort.IsOpen)
    {
        e.Cancel = true; 
        Thread CloseDown = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CloseSerialOnExit)); 
        CloseDown.Start();
    }
}

private void CloseSerialOnExit()
{
    try
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(NowClose)); 
}

private void NowClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close(); //now close the form
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    _serialPort.Close(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    string data = _serialPort.ReadLine();
```

There is no lack of *potential* trouble with this statement.  You have a pretty nasty failure-mode on your hands when this call doesn't complete.  It doesn't have to, you could turn off the serial device at just the wrong time, jerk the cable, get the line terminator corrupted and you'll have a pretty big headache.

The SerialPort.Close() method cannot complete until any of the event handlers stop running.  This can significantly increase the odds for deadlock.  Using the ReadLine() method is fine, but then you *also* have to set the ReadTimeout property to, say, 10 seconds so you can be sure that accidents don't turn into undebuggable problems.  Let the TimeoutException either terminate your program or set a "serial port is dead" status variable.

Further improve the odds for success by disassociating the lifetime of the SerialPort with the lifetime of your form.  In general the only sensible thing to do is to create the instance at program startup and not close it until your program terminates.  Just keep it in a separate class, it can be *static* to make it easy to use.

And, unintuitively, it is now no longer important to call Close() at all.  The finalizer will take care of it.

Also make sure that, if you use a USB emulator, to **never** disconnect it without going through the Safely Remove Hardware tray icon.  USB drivers generally deal with a surprise removal very poorly.  Some are so poor that they make the device disappear even though you have it opened.  And trying to close it always fails, you cannot cleanly exit your program anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Actually, it's just the way back to my first idea : Open a port on my program start-up !